# Follow-up: Removing an item from an std:: vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

In the 1st code snippet below, I am trying to remove an element from a vector within a member function based on a static condition function fed into std::remove_if function. My problem here is that the input parameter uuid in removeVipAddress method cannot accessed within the condition function. What do you think I should do here to enable removal of an item from the vector based on the input parameter named uuid? Thanks. NOte: This is a follow up problem explained previously in [Removing an item from an std:: vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025083/removing-an-item-from-an-std-vector)

**SNIPPET 1 (CODE)**

```
void removeVipAddress(std::string &uuid)
{
          struct RemoveCond
          {
            static bool condition(const VipAddressEntity & o)
            {
              return o.getUUID() == uuid;
            }
          };

          std::vector<VipAddressEntity>::iterator last =
            std::remove_if(
                    mVipAddressList.begin(),
                    mVipAddressList.end(),
                    RemoveCond::condition);

          mVipAddressList.erase(last, mVipAddressList.end());

}
```

**SNIPPET 2** (COMPILATION OUTPUT)

```
 $ g++ -g -c -std=c++11 -Wall Entity.hpp
 Entity.hpp: In static member function ‘static bool ECLBCP::VipAddressSet::removeVipAddress(std::string&)::RemoveCond::condition(const   ECLBCP::VipAddressEntity&)’:
 Entity.hpp:203:32: error: use of parameter from containing function
 Entity.hpp:197:7: error:   ‘std::string& uuid’ declared here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using C++11 this could be done with a lambda:

```
auto last = std::remove_if(
     mVipAddressList.begin(),
     mVipAddressList.end(),
     [uuid]( const VipAddressEntity& o ){
          return o.getUUID() == uuid;
     });
```

The last parameter on that function call declares a lambda, which is an anonymous inline function.  The `[uuid]` bit tells it to include `uuid` in the scope of the lambda.

There's a tutorial on lambdas [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html)

Alternatively you probably want to provide a constructor & member function to your RemoveCond predicate (and implement it using operator() rather than a function named condition).

Something like this:

```
struct RemoveCond
{
    RemoveCond( const std::string& uuid ) :
    m_uuid( uuid )
    {
    }

    bool operator()(const VipAddressEntity & o)
    {
        return o.getUUID() == m_uuid;
    }

    const std::string& m_uuid;
};

std::remove_if( 
     mVipAddressList.begin(),
     mVipAddressList.end(),
     RemoveCond( uuid );
     );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have C++11 lambdas, you could express your `RemoveCond` as a functor:

```
struct RemoveCond
{
  RemoveCond(const std::string uuid) : uuid_(uuid) {}
  bool operator()(const VipAddressEntity & o) const
  {
          return o.getUUID() == uuid_;
  }
  const std::string& uuid_;
};
```

then pass an instance to `std::remove_if`:

```
std::remove_if(mVipAddressList.begin(),
               mVipAddressList.end(),
               RemoveCond(uuid));
```

BTW you `removeVipAddress` function should take a `const` reference:

```
void removeVipAddress(const std::string &uuid)
```